# this.form.submit(); submit all form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms

This probably a simple answer but I can't seems to understand the logic here.

I have multiple form in the same page and I use this structure on most of them:

```
<form name="" action="../charmodif/charinfo.php?charname=<?php echo $name ?>" method="post">
    <input onblur="this.form.submit();" type="text" name="actualxp" value="<?php echo $infochar['actualxp']; ?>">
<form>
```

The main part of my php processing file:
    $charname = $_GET['charname'];

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $field)
{
    mysqli_query($conn,"
    UPDATE `character`
    SET `" . $field . "`='" . $_POST[$field] . "'
    WHERE name='" . $charname . "';
    ");
}
```

The problem I have is that it actually seems to submit all form in the page at the same time. It result in my php function to process the MySQL for every form at the same time.

I verified this using simple echo with the POST in the php action.

It seems to me that the bigger is the page, the longer it's going to take to process the data. It's mainly for performance than anything else since it's actually working very well anyway.

How can I have this simple form submit it for itself only? Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: That's because you never close the forms so you only have one big form, it should be `</form>`

Comment: Also, $_POST['charname'] instead of $_GET['charname']

Comment: Submitting on blur? I bet that causes serious usability issues with those who use a keyboard for navigation. How do they ever get past the first tab index?

Comment: I'm using this for an interactive  character sheet for a roleplay game. I actually need each input to be directly updated in the database on each change to simulate live change. This is not a usual form for a usual website :)

Comment: I actually just discover onchange which is even better! Thanks for making me search for it :D

Comment: @DrizztDoUrden you have security issues in pretty much every line of that code, id have some real fun with your datasets...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last line:

```
<form name="" action="../charmodif/charinfo.php?charname=<?php echo $name ?>" method="post">
    <input onblur="this.form.submit();" type="text" name="actualxp" value="<?php echo $infochar['actualxp']; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted to know. I searched for my error for like 30 minutes. Think I am blind :P